# Update Localization array value

Tags: php, laravel, localization, storage

I am updating values of files under the lang folder. All files has an array and I want to update that array's value from user.

For example,

`en/messages.php` files has array like

```
<?php 
    return [
       'hello' => 'hi'
    ];
```

Now I am sending these pairs to users. A user can able to change the only value of that label.

What I have done is

```
public function update(Request $request, $lang, $file)
{
   $r = $request->input('lang');
   Storage::put('lang/' . $lang . '/' . $file.'.php', $r);
   return redirect()->back();
}
```

But I am getting only values of that array. I want the output in a file like:

Desired Output:

```
<?php
   return [
      'hello' => 'helo'
   ];
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php

Comment: `array:3 [▼
  "Dashboard" => "Tableau de bord"
  "login" => "s'identifier"
  "registre" => "registre"
]`    I am getting this array but when i put it in file it stored like `Tableau de bords'identifierregistre`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am done this by this way,

```
    public function update(Request $request, $lang, $file)
    {
            $r = $request->input('lang');
            $textContent = " <?php  
                return [ ";
            foreach ($r as $label => $value) {
                $textContent .= '"' . $label . '" => "' . $value . '",';
            }
            $textContent .= '];';
            Storage::put('lang/' . $lang . '/' . $file . '.php', $textContent);
            return back();
        }
```